# Problema en consulta NOT IN

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un problema con una consulta, en principio muy fácil.

Creé una tabla `control_de_stock` donde está la información del stock de miles de artículos, cada uno de ellos con su `"id producto"`. Creé otra tabla `ordenes_de_venta` donde también existen `"id producto"` y que es la encargada de registrar cada venta que se haya realizado.

Quiero poder averiguar que productos no se han vendido nunca. Para ello realicé esta consulta. Por separado sí veo que en control de stock hay muchas más id's que en ordenes_de_venta, pero sin embargo al ejecutar la consulta muestra 0 filas.

```
select distinct "id producto" from control_de_stock
    where "id producto" not in
        (select distinct "id producto" from ordenes_de_venta);
```

Aparte de la solución me gustaría saber qué estoy haciendo mal o una explicación de por qué me está ocurriendo esto.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Es más fácil si haces

```
SELECT distinct cs.id_producto 
FROM control_de_stock cs
LEFT JOIN ordenes_de_venta USING (id_producto)
WHERE ordenes_de_venta.id_producto IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que existía un valor nulo o vacío en ordenes_de_venta y no permitía que la consulta funcionase.

He utilizado el siguiente código para que funcione:

```
select distinct "id producto" from control_de_stock cs
    where cs."id producto" NOT IN 
        (select distinct "id producto" from ordenes_de_venta where "id producto" > 1) order by "id producto";
```